# How to improve the reliability of my robot's localization?

Tags: imu, navigation, odometry, robot-localization, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

### Context

I have a differential drive robot with 4 wheels, similar to the Clearpath Jackal. It moves in a closed environment in indoor and outdoor, and the map is known. It is equipped with a laser range, an IMU, and odometry is computed thanks to wheel encoders. The robot is also equipped with a GPS, but I would prefer not to use it for now.

Some area of the map (outdoor) are such that the robot walk through "weak" localization phases due too lack of landmarks.
I am trying to improve the localization chain, to be more robust to these "weak" localization phases.

Basically what I am trying to do is to be able to navigate in a degraded mode whitout being completely lost (i.e. AMCL could be lost temporarily but tf map -> odom would still be available).

### Setup

[image: Setup]

I use a first "local" robot_localization instance to fuse odom and imu data. This outputs what I called /odom/filtered.
Next I have an AMCL instance, which takes as input laser range measurements and /odom/filtered.
Then I fuse the AMCL position, odom and imu with a second "global" robot_localization instance.
The first local ekf_localizer provides odom -> base_link transform
The second global ekf_localizer provides map -> odom

The output of the first local ekf_localization is really good as I can see in rviz (The robot return to about 1m from it's departure point after a loop of 93m x 35m, cf image).

[image: odom(blue) vs odom filtered(red)]

odom(blue) vs odom filtered(red)

- **Os:** Ubuntu Server 14.04 with ROS Indigo
- **Localization:** [robot_localization](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization) (v2.3.0) package with [AMCL](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl) (v 1.12.13)
- **Visualization:** To visualize the covariance of the position and odometry, the [rviz_plugin_covariance](https://github.com/laas/rviz_plugin_covariance) is used.

### AMCL Covariance problem

All this chain is based on the covariance of the respective measurements. So the covariance matrix values must be as representative of the reality as possible and it seems that's not the case.

At first I thought that the position covariance provided by AMCL was an estimation of how confident AMCL is on the current robot position in the map, but I am not sure. By displaying the covariance, I see that the robot localization is inside an ellipsoid about 20 to 30cm in diameter when it is well localized.

Note: For readability purpose,  the displayed ellipsoid is 3sigma (estimated position +- 3 times the standard deviation)

[image: Well Localized]

When AMCL begin to get lost the covariance increase significantly,

[image: Not well localized]

and then decrease to, again, 20 to 30 cm in diameter, but with AMCL sometimes being really lost !

[image: Lost]

Why this strange behavior ? This causes the global ekf_localization to "trust" the position more than the odometry.
In an attempt to workaround this behavior, I tried a naive approach : if the covariance ellipsoid is more than 50cm in diameter, I stop sending the AMCL position to the global ekf node. When the diameter is less than 50cm, I send the current estimated positon as initial position of AMCL. In some way it works well, but the reinitialization of AMCL is worse than expected : most of the time it founds an erroneous position. I need a way to estimate the quality of the AMCL output.
I found this : https://github.com/dejanpan/snap_map_icp which is a node which performs an ICP (Iterative Closest Point) to get a corrected pose and reset amcl particule distribution, but I haven't tried it yet.

### Global ekf covariance

Another problem is the value of the global ekf covariance: when I momentarily disable AMCL pose input, the covariance begin to increase. That's normal, because the filter is only fed with odom and imu measurements. But it increase a lot: for example, the robot moving in strait line, after a few meters the incertitude ellipsoid displayed can reach several meters. This does not reflect the reality of the output of the first local ekf.
Is this a normal behavior ? or my covariance values for odom and or imu are bad ?

[image: odometry_covariance]

```
odom.twist.covariance[covIndex(0, 0)] = 0.002304;
odom.twist.covariance[covIndex(1, 1)] = 1e-6; //Very small because non holonomous robot
odom.twist.covariance[covIndex(2, 2)] = 1e-6; //very small because not measured ?
odom.twist.covariance[covIndex(3, 3)] = 1e-6; //very small because not measured ?
odom.twist.covariance[covIndex(4, 4)] = 1e-6; //very small because not measured ?
odom.twist.covariance[covIndex(5, 5)] = 0.00188411;
```

The covariance values for linear speed and angular speed are the result of specific measurement, so these are good.
I have a doubt about (2,2) (3,3) and (4,4) if they need to be really big or really small... But it's not so important as the corresponding value are disabled in input of the ekf node.

```
//Position covariance is supposed to increase because robot's position drifts ??`
odom.pose.covariance[covIndex(0, 0)] = 0.01;
odom.pose.covariance[covIndex(1, 1)] = 0.01;
odom.pose.covariance[covIndex(2, 2)] = 1e-6;
odom.pose.covariance[covIndex(3, 3)] = 1e-6;
odom.pose.covariance[covIndex(4, 4)] = 1e-6;
odom.pose.covariance[covIndex(5, 5)] = 0.1;
```

For now the odometry pose covariance values are fixed, but I think they should increase over time. If I understand, fixed values should give me a smaller covariance than the real one, so this does not explain the big covariance values I have.

IMU Covariance (Computed from datasheet parameters):

```
imu angular_velocity_covariance(0, 0) = 2.7415569547883933e-07
imu angular_velocity_covariance(1, 1) = 2.7415569547883933e-07
imu angular_velocity_covariance(2, 2) = 2.7415569547883933e-07
linear_acceleration_covariance(0, 0) = 7.789801020408049e-05
linear_acceleration_covariance(1, 1) = 7.789801020408049e-05
linear_acceleration_covariance(2, 2) = 7.789801020408049e-05
```

Configuration of the first "local" EKF node:

```
frequency: 20 
two_d_mode: true

# X, Y, Z
# roll, pitch, yaw
# X vel, Y vel, Z vel
# roll vel, pitch vel, yaw vel
# X accel, Y accel, Z accel

#Odometry input config 
odom0: /odom 
odom0_config: [false, false, false,
               false, false, false,
               true, true, false,
               false, false, true,
               false, false, false] 
odom0_differential: false 
odom0_relative: true

#IMU input config 
imu0: /imu_data 
imu0_config: [false, false, false,
              false, false, false,
              false, false, false,
              true, true, true,
              false, false, false]
imu0_differential: false 
imu0_relative: true 
imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: false

#Frames config 
odom_frame: odom 
base_link_frame: base_link 
world_frame: odom
```

Configuration of the "global" EKF node:

```
frequency: 10
two_d_mode: true

# X, Y, Z
# roll, pitch, yaw
# X vel, Y vel, Z vel
# roll vel, pitch vel, yaw vel
# X accel, Y accel, Z accel

#Odometry input config
odom0: /odom
odom0_config: [false, false, false,
               false, false, false,
               true, true, false,
               false, false, true,
               false, false, false]
odom0_differential: false
odom0_relative: true

#IMU input config
imu0: /imu_data
imu0_config: [false, false, false,
              false, false, false,
              false, false, false,
              true, true, true,
              false, false, false]
imu0_differential: false
imu0_relative: true
imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: false

#Pose from localizer
pose0: /localizer/pose_filtered
pose0_config: [true, true, false,
               false, false, true,
               false, false, false,
               false, false, false,
               false, false, false]
pose0_differential: false
pose0_relative: false

#Frames config
odom_frame: odom
base_link_frame: base_link
world_frame: map
```

If you have any thought about all this setup, it would be really appreciated.
Thanks in advance

#### Update1:

Relative to @TomMoore answer.
I tuned the process_noise_covariance for both of the ekf_localization nodes, and it improved a lot the resulting output covariance.

**Edit:** I updated a new screenshot showing when all data is fused (odom, imu, amcl pose) in green and when only odom and imu are fused in orange.

[image: degraded mode vs all fused]

I added in both configuration files :

```
process_noise_covariance: [0.0001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                           0.0, 0.0001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                           0.0, 0.0, 0.0001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                           0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                           0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                           0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                           0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                           0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                           0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                           0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                           0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                           0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                           0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0001, 0.0, 0.0,
                           0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0001, 0.0,
                           0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0001]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247517/how-to-improve-the-reliability-of-my-robot%27s-localization-?/) by [Inounx](https://answers.ros.org/users/28459/inounx/) on ROS Answers with karma: 293 on 2016-11-08

Post score: 16

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2016-11-08**:
Great question! I'll need some time to look over it, but I'll respond.

**Comment by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on 2016-11-08**:
You've done a great job clearly outlining your problem and providing plenty of explanation. I probably won't be able to help too much, but if you can provide a short bagfile or two with all your data that will definitely help others answer your question.

**Comment by [Inounx](https://answers.ros.org/users/28459/inounx/) on 2016-11-09**:
Thanks, I will try to make a small package with everything needed included, to easily replay this scenario.

**Comment by [Inounx](https://answers.ros.org/users/28459/inounx/) on 2016-11-09**:
Here is the catkin package with a rosbag included: [localization_replay.tar.bz2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v6kxrbpob0v38kp/localization_replay.tar.bz2?dl=0)

All the config is done (rviz too), just add to a catkin workspace, build, and `roslaunch localization_replay localization_replay.launch`

**Comment by [Inounx](https://answers.ros.org/users/28459/inounx/) on 2016-11-14**:
I have some warnings from both robot_localization nodes : `Transform from imu to base_link was unavailable for the time requested. Using latest instead.` I think it comes from the non-synchronization between /odom /imu_data and /amcl_pose, but maybe I am wrong ?

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2016-11-14**:
Sounds to me like you are using a regular tf `static_transform_broadcaster` instead of a `tf2` one. Is that true?

**Comment by [Inounx](https://answers.ros.org/users/28459/inounx/) on 2016-11-14**:
I am using `robot_state_publisher` with an urdf model. The default parameters are used, so `use_tf_static` is false. I didn't heard about tf2 before, so yes I guess, I am using regular tf. I will look into it.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2016-11-17**:
Why do I see lateral "jumps" in your robot pose as it goes around the curve? Is the `amcl` pose estimate being fused at that point?

**Comment by [Inounx](https://answers.ros.org/users/28459/inounx/) on 2016-11-17**:
Yes exactly, what is displayed here is the output of the global ekf_localization node. I am trying to find a good way to display with rviz when amcl pose is fused, and when it's not (color change?), as the transition between the two is not always clear.

**Comment by [adityakamath](https://answers.ros.org/users/28154/adityakamath/) on 2017-06-22**:
Thanks for such a detailed description of your problem! I have been working on something similar and your catkin package helped me solve some issues in my ROS config. I would like to reference and acknowledge your work in my master thesis. Can you give me your email, so I can contact you?

**Comment by [linusnie](https://answers.ros.org/users/30863/linusnie/) on 2017-06-27**:
Hi @inounx! This is off topic, but what do you use to plot the covariance ellipsoids in your pictures? I have been looking for something like this, but afaik it is not possible in the standard rviz.

**Comment by [Inounx](https://answers.ros.org/users/28459/inounx/) on 2017-07-10**:
@adityakamath Hi, my email is in the package.xml in the archive you downloaded.
@linusnie Hi, It is written in the fist post... It rviz_plugin_covariance, works with indigo, but not with kinetic AFAIK

**Comment by [fj138696](https://answers.ros.org/users/30352/fj138696/) on 2017-07-31**:
HI [@Inounx](http://answers.ros.org/users/28459/inounx/)! may i know what IMU model you are using? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here are the last modifications I did to improve this localization system, as I think it is not useful to let this post open forever.
Note: this is not (for now) a complete solution, as there are still some points to be improved.

I adapted and tried the icp I mentionned in my question : in practice, the results are not so good. It is computationally expensive and does not really improve AMCL localization. I had some cases where the ICP gave worse results than AMCL, so I decided to not use it.

To check the AMCL output I project the lidar point cloud :

- once to the position given by AMCL
- once to the global fused position (output of global ekf node)

and check how much it matches with the map : if AMCL is the best match, position is sent to the global ekf to be fused.
if global ekf is the best match, I send the current global position to amcl.
If neither ekf match nor amcl match are good, we stay in "degraded" mode for a maximum distance waiting to get again a good match.

In pratice it works pretty well, excepted in open areas where a certain distance is travelled and AMCL do not manage to re-localize successfully. The difficulty here is to set a good threshold to consider when a match is "good enough" or not.

**Improvement to be made**

Some improvement can still be made :

- When AMCL begin to be lost its computation time to give a position increase significantly, maybe it can be used as another indicator to detect when it is lost. It is kind of ugly because setting a threshold here is dependent on the hardware and actual computation load from other nodes...
- Keep track of the count of "landmark" points in the map in a radius around the robot, and if there are too few points, stop fusing AMCL poses as there is not enough landmarks to be localized.

---

Originally posted by [Inounx](https://answers.ros.org/users/28459/inounx/) with karma: 293 on 2017-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lotfi_Z](https://answers.ros.org/users/41048/lotfi_z/) on 2019-06-05**:
Hi Inoux,
First, i have to tell that you did a very good job in the AMCL issue explanation, i have facing the same problem and i think that it can be solved with a point to map ICP, do you think that you can share with us the method that you used or some tips on how to achieve that ? Thank you very much

**Comment by [Inounx](https://answers.ros.org/users/28459/inounx/) on 2019-06-10**:
@Lofti_Z Hi, I didn't use the ICP in the end, check the https://github.com/dejanpan/snap_map_icp package, it should give you a good start.

**Comment by [Danny_PR2](https://answers.ros.org/users/44786/danny_pr2/) on 2021-03-03**:
Thanks for the excellent question. Could you please share how does the system operates during "degraded mode" ?

**Comment by [Muhd Hizam](https://answers.ros.org/users/88237/muhd-hizam/) on 2021-11-17**:
Hi, this is an excellent question. Sorry if my query is very dated, but can I ask how did you check whether the AMCL or global EKF provides the best match to the lidar point cloud? Did you use any algo to calculate some metric score?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I have yet to run your test package, and I can't speak at all to the `amcl` issues, but re: the EKF covariance, for any given time step, there are three covariance matrices that matter:

1. The estimate error covariance (the error for the entire state)
2. The process noise covariance (how much noise we add to the filter every time we do a prediction)
3. The measurement covariance (the error in the measurement itself)

At every time step, we make a prediction about where we should be, given the motion model, and the also make a prediction about what the estimate error covariance matrix will be. The equation for prediction is this:

```
P = JPJ' + Q
```

`Q` is the process noise covariance matrix. In general, if your pose covariance is growing too quickly, you'll want to check the values for your pose AND twist variables in the `process_noise_covariance` parameter for the EKF. The odometry twist covariances are also important, so you can tune those as well.

**EDIT 1** in response to comment question:

In many Kalman Filter formulations, I believe the time step is assumed to be constant, so `Q` is also constant. In the state estimation nodes in `r_l`, `Q` gets multiplied by the time delta, so the `process_noise_covariance` parameter is how much process noise you'd accumulate *per second.* This is necessary in order to cope with the measurements arriving at uncertain intervals. Tuning the values for `Q` is not easy, and, from what I've seen, is typically done by watching the error growth and determining if it's reasonable (i.e., hand tuning).

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2016-11-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Inounx](https://answers.ros.org/users/28459/inounx/) on 2016-11-17**:
Thanks for your answer! If I understand correctly, what your are saying is that the process noise covariance `Q` is added during the state estimation process, so the values in this matrix must be choosen according to the `frequency` parameter ?

**Comment by [Inounx](https://answers.ros.org/users/28459/inounx/) on 2016-11-17**:
Ok, it's much clearer now. With a few tests and a process noise covariance at 0.0001 in the diagonal values, I get pretty good results. I will update my post as soon as I have some nice screenshots.